# How do FileAppenders work in Java

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to understand the inner details of how FileAppenders work in java. I am using log4j as my logging framework.

More specifically I want to understand interaction between FileHandles and Appender. What are implications of ever swelling log files.

If you can point me to technical details of logging frameworks, or articles that can help me understand various Appenders and their performance implications(not just the list of appenders), that might be a great help for me.

Comment: This might be useful reference. [log4j_performance_tips](http://fredpuls.com/site/softwaredevelopment/java/log4j/log4j_performance_tips.htm)

Comment: Have you tried reading the source code?